# Emacs force org-mode capture buffer to open in a new window

Tags: emacs, org-mode

How do I force org-mode's capture buffer to open in a new window? I tried

```
(setq special-display-regexps
    '("^\\*Capture\\*$"))
```

but it did not work - I see a new window momentarily and then org-mode makes two vertical splits (I'm using 3 vertical splits), and put the capture buffer into the right split. When I'm done by either `C-c C-c` or `C-c C-k`, the original split setting is restored.

Comment: Without modifying a few of the core capture functions that control the target window, what you seek is difficult.  If there is not another solution offered, I'll see if there is a more simple solution.  I have taken all the capture functions and renamed them and modified them to remove the stuff that controls target and that restores prior stored window configurations.

Comment: After playing it around a little bit I figured it would be just like you said. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: If you'd like to take a look at `org-capture.el`, you can do a quick word search for the following entries to get a better idea of what's happening:  `(org-pop-to-buffer-same-window (org-capture-get :buffer))`; `(org-pop-to-buffer-same-window (get-buffer-create "*Capture*"))`; `(org-capture-put :return-to-wconf (current-window-configuration))`; `(set-window-configuration (org-capture-get :return-to-wconf))`.  `org-pop-to-buffer-same-window` is defined within `org-compat.el`.  I chose to remove all that stuff and create new functions using `with-current-buffer` and then display in my own way.

Comment: Reviving this momentarily because I'm trying to prevent `org-capture` from modifying my window configuration.  a), did you figure this out?  If not, b), do you just want the `capture` buffer to open in a different *window* without modifying your three-across setup, or are you asking if you can open the `capture` buffer in a new *frame*?

Comment: No unfortunately. Currently I'm just using simple 2 vertical splits and having bunch of temporary stuff (compilation, etc) shows up in a new frame. I wanted to have the capture shows up in a new frame. But it really does not matter - I just wanted the capture buffer not to change my original splits.

Comment: The answer below keeps `org-capture` from modifying the window configuration, but does not raise the `capture` buffer in it's own frame.  You could get it to do so, but it would require modifying the functions that finalize the capture as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I, too, like to use many side-by-side splits (usually 4 -- I'm spread across multiple monitors), so `org-capture`'s behavior of turning 4 regular windows into 2 really wide ones makes my head explode every time -- which tends to knock me out of my flow.

```
+---+---+---+---+     +-------+-------+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | --> |   1   |capture| = head explosion
+---+---+---+---+     +-------+-------+
```

So here's a way to prevent `org-capture` from modifying your window configuration.

After some searching, it does not look like there is an easy way to customize this behavior (or at least not an obvious one).  Tracing the function calls in the source code brings us to `org-capture-place-template`, which saves your original window configuration, *then deletes the other windows*, then gives you the two-window split.  You get your window configuration back later when you finalize the capture, of course, but it sure would be nice to get rid of that "let's change your window layout without your say-so" step.

Turns out it's pretty simple.  Just re-evaluate `org-capture-place-template` after commenting out the single line calling `(delete-other-windows)`:

```lisp
(defun org-capture-place-template ()
  "Insert the template at the target location, and display the buffer."
  (org-capture-put :return-to-wconf (current-window-configuration))
  ;; (delete-other-windows)                ; this is the culprit!
  (org-switch-to-buffer-other-window
   (org-capture-get-indirect-buffer (org-capture-get :buffer) "CAPTURE"))
  (widen)
  (show-all)
  (goto-char (org-capture-get :pos))
  (org-set-local 'org-capture-target-marker
         (point-marker))
  (org-set-local 'outline-level 'org-outline-level)
  (let* ((template (org-capture-get :template))
     (type (org-capture-get :type)))
    (case type
      ((nil entry) (org-capture-place-entry))
      (table-line (org-capture-place-table-line))
      (plain (org-capture-place-plain-text))
      (item (org-capture-place-item))
      (checkitem (org-capture-place-item))))
  (org-capture-mode 1)
  (org-set-local 'org-capture-current-plist org-capture-plist))
```

Aaaah.  It was like `org-capture` was punching me in the face every time I used it, but now it's stopped.

---

(Edited: the following is for a newer version of org-mode)

```lisp
(defun org-capture-place-template (&optional inhibit-wconf-store)
  "Insert the template at the target location, and display the buffer.
When `inhibit-wconf-store', don't store the window configuration, as it
may have been stored before."
  (unless inhibit-wconf-store
    (org-capture-put :return-to-wconf (current-window-configuration)))
  ;(delete-other-windows)
  (org-switch-to-buffer-other-window
   (org-capture-get-indirect-buffer (org-capture-get :buffer) "CAPTURE"))
  (widen)
  (show-all)
  (goto-char (org-capture-get :pos))
  (org-set-local 'org-capture-target-marker
         (point-marker))
  (org-set-local 'outline-level 'org-outline-level)
  (let* ((template (org-capture-get :template))
     (type (org-capture-get :type)))
    (case type
      ((nil entry) (org-capture-place-entry))
      (table-line (org-capture-place-table-line))
      (plain (org-capture-place-plain-text))
      (item (org-capture-place-item))
      (checkitem (org-capture-place-item))))
  (org-capture-mode 1)
  (org-set-local 'org-capture-current-plist org-capture-plist))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just pasted this code to a buffer and evaluated it, but then capture did not work. It did not destroy my setup and showed ``Select a capture template`` successfully, but when I chose a template, it showed bunch of code in the Minibuffer.

Comment: It seems the code is changed a bit since. I copied the code from http://orgmode.org/w/?p=org-mode.git;a=blob_plain;f=lisp/org-capture.el;hb=HEAD and commented out the same ``(delete-other-windows)`` line, and it started working normally.

Comment: I came up with an [alternative version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54251825/113848) that should be more resistant to future Org-mode code changes.

Comment: Sadly I ran this and got an error about `org-set-local` function definition being void

Comment: It looks like org-set-local is no longer available. I was getting this error too and fixed it by using `setq-local` instead.

Comment: I solved the first issue using the `setq-local`, but now I'm getting the error `Wrong type argument: symbolp, (quote org-capture-target-marker)`

Answer (score 4):

Here's the solution I came up with.  This causes the entire capture process to occur in a single pop-out frame.

First, a couple of helper functions.

```
(defun my/get-frame-by-name (fname)
  "If there is a frame with named FNAME, return it, else nil."
  (require 'dash)                       ; For `-some'
  (-some (lambda (frame)
           (when (equal fname (frame-parameter frame 'name))
             frame))
         (frame-list)))

(defun my/display-buffer-in-named-frame (buffer alist)
  "Display BUFFER in frame with specific name.
The name to use is the value associated with the 'named-frame key
in ALIST.  If a frame with that name already exists, use it.
Otherwise, call `display-buffer-in-pop-up-frame' to create it.

If ALIST does not contain the key 'named-frame, use the name of BUFFER."
  (let* ((fname  (or (cdr (assq 'named-frame alist))
                     (buffer-name buffer)))
         (frame  (my/get-frame-by-name fname)))
    (if frame
        (window--display-buffer buffer
                                (frame-selected-window frame)
                                'reuse) 
      (display-buffer-pop-up-frame
       buffer
       (add-to-list 'alist `(pop-up-frame-parameters
                             (name . ,fname)))))))
```

Next, a macro to install temporary advice.  If you prefer, you could inline this pretty easily.

```
(defmacro my/with-advice (adlist &rest body)
  "Execute BODY with temporary advice in ADLIST.

Each element of ADLIST should be a list of the form
  (SYMBOL WHERE FUNCTION [PROPS])
suitable for passing to `advice-add'.  The BODY is wrapped in an
`unwind-protect' form, so the advice will be removed even in the
event of an error or nonlocal exit."
  (declare (debug ((&rest (&rest form)) body))
           (indent 1))
  `(progn
     ,@(mapcar (lambda (adform)
                 (cons 'advice-add adform))
               adlist)
     (unwind-protect (progn ,@body)
       ,@(mapcar (lambda (adform)
                   `(advice-remove ,(car adform) ,(nth 2 adform)))
                 adlist))))
```

Here's the main function.  The idea is to temporarily override everything that Org-mode is doing that we don't want.  This includes the `delete-other-windows` call mentioned in Dan's answer, and also two calls to `org-switch-to-buffer-other-window`, which explicitly blocks pop-out frames.

```
(defun my/org-capture-in-popout-frame (&optional goto keys)
  "As `org-capture', but do all work in a new frame.

    This function by itself doesn't clean up the frame following
    capture.  To do that, add `my/org-capture-delete-capture-frame'
    to `org-capture-after-finalize-hook'."
  (interactive "P")
  (if goto
      (org-capture goto keys)
    (let ((override  '("\\*Org Select\\*\\|\\*Capture\\*\\|CAPTURE-.*"
                       my/display-buffer-in-named-frame
                       (named-frame . "Capture"))))
      ;; Force all relevant buffers to open in a specific capture frame.
      (add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist override)
      (my/with-advice 
          (;; Make Org-mode respect `display-buffer-alist'.
           (#'org-switch-to-buffer-other-window :override #'pop-to-buffer)
           ;; And stop Org-mode from messing with our window configuration.
           (#'delete-other-windows :override #'ignore))
        (unwind-protect (condition-case err
                            (org-capture goto keys)
                          (error (my/org-capture-delete-capture-frame)
                                 (signal (car err) (cdr err))))
          (setq display-buffer-alist
                (delete override display-buffer-alist)))))))
```

To get rid of the frame after capture is complete, use this function:

```
(defun my/org-capture-delete-capture-frame ()
  "Delete a frame named \"Capture\".
For use in `org-capture-after-finalize-hook' to clean up after
`my/org-capture-in-popout-frame'."
  (let ((frame  (my/get-frame-by-name "Capture")))
    (when frame (delete-frame frame))))
```

This is already called by `my/capture-in-popout-frame` in the event of an early abort (e.g., typing `q` in the template selection buffer or `C-g` in response to a prompt in a capture template).  For normal completion (including refiling) or a late abort (`C-c C-k` from the capture template), you need to add it to `org-capture-after-finalize-hook`.

```
(add-hook 'org-capture-after-finalize-hook
          #'my/org-capture-delete-capture-frame)
```

Note that none of these functions modify the way independent calls to `org-capture` work (unless for some reason you have an extra frame named "Capture" lying around), so you can still get the default behavior if you want it for a particular capture.

One caveat:  This won't support multiple simultaneous capture processes.  I don't have a need for that personally, but if you do, I don't think it should be too hard to add that capability.