# Open Org Capture buffer in specific window?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I've been an Emacs user for about a year or so. I routinely have the same window set up each session (four windows).

I've set up capture templates and can capture what I want, but: instead of capture mode temporarily jerking me out of my window setup, I'd like the chosen capture template to open in a new (fifth) window, preserving my existing layout. I typically want the capture template open for a while, so it's disruptive.

This *seems* like it would be an obvious option, but I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance to all the Emacs heads out there.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25335933/113848) do what you want?

Comment: @legoscia No, unfortunately. That 'approved' answer doesn't work, and the link in the comments doesn't work, either.

Comment: There is no option to do that: you'd have to rewrite the function `org-capture-place-template` to implement a different strategy.

Comment: @James: I just tried commenting out the `(delete-other-windows)` in `org-capture-place-template` as in the answer that @legoscia pointed out, and that works fine: the capture buffer opens in one of the existing windows, the other windows stick around unchanged, and when the capture is finalized, the modified window goes to its previous state. You should not copy the function from that answer however: you should edit the `org-capture.el` file that *you* are using, possibly recompile the file if you are running with compiled code and then do `M-x org-reload` to activate the change.

Comment: @NickD I'm only a year or so into Emacs, and I don't *think* I use an `org-capture.el` file. My only config file is a `.emacs` file.

Comment: As I said, this is not configuration: you have to modify the `org-capture-place-template` function. But you *do* have the *file* `org-capture.el` somewhere: do `M-x locate-file org-capture.el` to find it. Then you can edit it, save it, compile it if necessary and reload `org-mode`. But I understand that you might find this a bit overwhelming: you might try @legoscia's answer below, which *can* be just added to your `.emacs`.

Comment: @NickD Ahh, now I see. I found `org-capture.el` and commented out `delete-other-windows` like you described--and it worked. I wasn't aware of the directory/file structure of packages, but now I've learned about that, too. Thanks for the responses, much appreciated. If

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I came up with a easier-to-use version of [Dan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25335933/113848) to the linked question:

```
(defun my-org-capture-place-template-dont-delete-windows (oldfun &rest args)
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'delete-other-windows) 'ignore))
    (apply oldfun args)))

(with-eval-after-load "org-capture"
  (advice-add 'org-capture-place-template :around 'my-org-capture-place-template-dont-delete-windows))
```

That is, instead of having to modify Org-mode code and remove the call to `delete-other-windows`, this piece of code temporarily redefines `delete-other-windows` to `ignore` while `org-capture-place-template` is being called.

It doesn't do quite what you want: it picks one of the existing windows and puts the capture buffer there.  At least it's better than the default behaviour of removing all previous windows but one.

There's probably a way to do what you want by customising the variable `display-buffer-alist`, but I couldn't figure it out...

Comment: Thank you, the article you initially linked to worked, once @NickD explained the detail about modifying `org-capture.el`. If your initial comment was an answer, I would mark it as best answer.

Comment: I think you should accept this answer: it contains the pointer to the other answer and it also contains a way to implement the moral equivalent of that other answer without having to modify the org sources themselves. You should probably try adding the code in the above answer to your .emacs and *not* make the modification to `org-capture.el`. That will save you from having to make the same modification every time you upgrade your version of org-mode.

Comment: @NickD Agreed. Done.

Comment: You could also use el-patch to patch org-capture after loading like so:
  
    (el-patch-feature org-capture) 
  (with-eval-after-load 'org-capture
    (el-patch-defun org-capture-place-template  (&optional inhibit-wconf-store)
      "Insert the template at the target location, and display the buffer.
When `inhibit-wconf-store', don't store the window configuration, as it
may have been stored before."
      (unless inhibit-wconf-store
 (org-capture-put :return-to-wconf (current-window-configuration)))
      (el-patch-remove (delete-other-windows))
    )

Comment: I tried this but got the error that `org-set-local`'s function definition is void

Comment: This code is buggy: you need to prefix `args` with `&rest`, i.e. `(defun my-org-capture-place-template-dont-delete-windows (oldfun &rest args) ...)`.  Without this modification, it doesn't work with org 9.5.2 and probably other versions.  Otherwise works very nicely, though.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use https://github.com/raxod502/el-patch and patch org-capture after loading (look for the (el-patch-remove (delete-other-windows))):

```
  (el-patch-feature org-capture) 
  (with-eval-after-load 'org-capture
    (el-patch-defun org-capture-place-template  (&optional inhibit-wconf-store)
      "Insert the template at the target location, and display the buffer.
When `inhibit-wconf-store', don't store the window configuration, as it
may have been stored before."
      (unless inhibit-wconf-store
    (org-capture-put :return-to-wconf (current-window-configuration)))
      (el-patch-remove (delete-other-windows))
      (org-switch-to-buffer-other-window
       (org-capture-get-indirect-buffer (org-capture-get :buffer) "CAPTURE"))
      (widen)
      (org-show-all)
      (goto-char (org-capture-get :pos))
      (setq-local outline-level 'org-outline-level)
      (pcase (org-capture-get :type)
    ((or `nil `entry) (org-capture-place-entry))
    (`table-line (org-capture-place-table-line))
    (`plain (org-capture-place-plain-text))
    (`item (org-capture-place-item))
    (`checkitem (org-capture-place-item)))
      (org-capture-mode 1)
      (setq-local org-capture-current-plist org-capture-plist)) )
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the @legoscia approach fails for me in emacs 28.

So here is the `el-patch` snippet as suggested previously:

```lisp
(el-patch-feature org-capture)
(with-eval-after-load 'org-capture
  (el-patch-define-and-eval-template
    (defun org-capture-place-template)
    (el-patch-remove (delete-other-windows))))
```